# Receiving push notification with Rover iOS 11

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

The iOS app I have been hired to build uses Batch and Rover. While I have had success in getting Batch to display an incoming notification, Rover is not even attempting to connect. I've been trying to figure this problem out for a few hours now. Here is my AppDelegate:

```
@import Batch;
@import Rover;
#import "app_appDelegate.h"
#import "BT_loading.h"

@implementation app_appDelegate


//didFinishLaunchingWithOptions...
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{
    [BT_debugger showIt:self message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"didFinishLaunchingWithOptions (iOS)%@", @""]];
    [Batch startWithAPIKey:@"_removed_"];
    [BatchPush registerForRemoteNotifications];
    [Rover setupWithApplicationToken:@"_removed_"];
    [Rover registerForNotifications];
    [Rover startMonitoring];

    NSDictionary *notificationPayload = launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];

    //    notificationPayload = @{@"nickname":@"Wine List 1"};
    [self appOpenDeepLink:notificationPayload];

    // Register for Push Notitications, if running iOS 8
    if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
        UIUserNotificationType userNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert |
                                                        UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                        UIUserNotificationTypeSound);
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:userNotificationTypes
                                                                                 categories:nil];
        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
        [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
    } else {
        // Register for Push Notifications before iOS 8
        [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                         UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
                                                         UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
        if (application.applicationState != UIApplicationStateBackground) {
            // Track an app open here if we launch with a push, unless
            // "content_available" was used to trigger a background push (introduced
            // in iOS 7). In that case, we skip tracking here to avoid double
            // counting the app-open.
            BOOL preBackgroundPush = ![application respondsToSelector:@selector(backgroundRefreshStatus)];
            BOOL oldPushHandlerOnly = ![self respondsToSelector:@selector(application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler: self: showDeepLinkScreen:userInfo:)];
            BOOL noPushPayload = ![launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
            if (preBackgroundPush || oldPushHandlerOnly || noPushPayload) {
                //[PFAnalytics trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions];


            }
        }


    }
    NSLog(@"Notification Payload: %@", notificationPayload);

    //hide status bar on launch...
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:TRUE withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];

    //setup the window on launch...
    [self setWindow:[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds]];
    [self.window setBackgroundColor:[BT_color getColorFromHexString:@"#FFFFFF"]];

    //load initial storyboard, "BT_loading"...
    UIStoryboard *launchStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"BT_loading" bundle:nil];
    BT_viewController *launchViewController = [launchStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BT_loading"];

    //set the rootViewController on the window to the BT_loading storyboard...
    self.window.rootViewController = launchViewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    //return...
    return TRUE;

}

- (void) appOpenDeepLink:(NSDictionary *) notificationPayload{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"screenNickname"];
    if(notificationPayload[@"nickname"]){
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:notificationPayload[@"nickname"] forKey:@"screenNickname"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }
}



//when app becomes active again
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application{

    //make sure we have an app...
    if([self rootApp] == nil){
        [BT_debugger showIt:self message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"applicationDidBecomeActive rootApp not available yet (iOS).%@", @""]];
    }else{

        [BT_debugger showIt:self message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"applicationDidBecomeActive (iOS)%@", @""]];

        //flag as visible...
        [self setUiIsVisible:TRUE];

        //report to cloud (not all apps do this, dataURL and reportToCloudURL required)...
        if([[self.rootApp dataURL] length] > 1 && [[self.rootApp reportToCloudURL] length] > 1){
            if(![self isRefreshing]){
                [self reportToCloud];
            }
        }

        //if we have a location manager...
        if([self rootLocationManager] != nil){
            [self.rootLocationManager setUpdateCount:0];
            [self.rootLocationManager.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
        }

    }
}

//promptforPushNotificationsAfterDelay...
-(void)promptforPushNotificationsAfterDelay{
    [BT_debugger showIt:self message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"promptforPushNotificationsAfterDelay%@", @""]];

    if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]){
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    }

}

//didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken...
-(void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken{
    [Rover didRegisterForRemoteNotificationWithDeviceToken:deviceToken];
    [BT_debugger showIt:self theMessage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken (iOS): Device Token: %@", deviceToken]];

    //if we have a token, and a  register it...
    if([deviceToken length] > 1 && [[self.rootApp registerForPushURL] length] > 1){

        //clean up token...
        NSString *useToken = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", deviceToken];
        useToken = [useToken stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<"withString:@""];
        useToken = [useToken stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">"withString:@""];
        useToken = [useToken stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" "withString:@""];

        //save it for next time...
        [BT_strings setPrefString:@"lastDeviceToken" valueOfPref:useToken];

        //append deviceToken and deviceType to end of URL...
        NSString *useURL = [[self.rootApp registerForPushURL] stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"&deviceType=%@", @"ios"]];
        useURL = [useURL stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"&deviceToken=%@", useToken]];

        //append currentMode ("Live" or "Design") to end of URL...
        useURL = [useURL stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"&currentMode=%@", [self currentMode]]];

        //merge environment variables in URL...
        useURL = [BT_strings mergeBTVariablesInString:useURL];

        //escape the URL...
        NSString *escapedUrl = [useURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        //tell the BT_device to register on the server (the device class makes the URL request)...
        [appDelegate.rootDevice registerForPushNotifications:escapedUrl];

    }

}


//didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError...
-(void)application:(UIApplication*)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError*)error{
    [BT_debugger showIt:self theMessage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError (iOS): ERROR: %@", error]];

}

//didReceiveRemoteNotification..
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo{
    [BT_debugger showIt:self theMessage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"didReceiveRemoteNotification (iOS)%@", @""]];

    //NSLog(@"Message ID: %@", userInfo);
    //NSLog(@"%@", userInfo);

    //(void)[Rover didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:nil];

    //don't do anything if the app is not in the foreground. iOS handles inbound APNS message when app is in the background...
    if(application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive){


        NSString *alertMsg;
        NSString *badge;
        NSString *sound;

        //alert message...
        if([[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"alert"] != NULL){
            alertMsg = [[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"alert"];
        }

        //badge...
        if([[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"badge"] != NULL){
            badge = [[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"badge"];
        }

        //sound...
        if([[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"sound"] != NULL){
            sound = [[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"sound"];
        }

        //if we have a sound...
        if([sound length] > 1){
            [self performSelector:@selector(playSoundFromPushMessage:) withObject:sound afterDelay:.1];
        }

        //show messsage...
        //UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"" message:alertMsg preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

        //UIAlertAction* MyAlert = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *alertTag)
        //  {
        // OK button tappped.
        //[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

        //}];

        //  }];
        // [alert addAction:MyAlert];
        //[[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController] presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

        //show messsage...
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:alertMsg delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"ok", "OK") otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];

        ////WATCH


    }//in foreground...
}

//playSoundFromPushMessage...
-(void)playSoundFromPushMessage:(NSString *)soundEffectFileName{
    [BT_debugger showIt:self theMessage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"playSoundFromPushMessage: %@", soundEffectFileName]];

    NSString *theFileName = soundEffectFileName;
    if([BT_fileManager doesFileExistInBundle:theFileName]){
        NSURL *soundFileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], theFileName]];
        NSError *error;
        AVAudioPlayer *tmpPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileUrl error:&error];
        if(!error){
            [tmpPlayer setNumberOfLoops:0];
            [tmpPlayer prepareToPlay];
            [tmpPlayer play];
        }else{
            [BT_debugger showIt:self theMessage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"didReceiveRemoteNotification soundEffectPlayer ERROR: %@", [error description]]];
        }
    }

}

//playSoundEffect...
-(void)playSoundEffect:(NSString *)theFileName{
    [BT_debugger showIt:self message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"playSoundEffect %@", theFileName]];
    if([theFileName length] > 3){

        if([self.rootSoundEffectPlayer.soundEffectNames containsObject:theFileName]){
            int playerIndex = (int)[self.rootSoundEffectPlayer.soundEffectNames indexOfObject:theFileName];
            AVAudioPlayer *tmpPlayer = (AVAudioPlayer *)[self.rootSoundEffectPlayer.soundEffectPlayers objectAtIndex:playerIndex];
            if(tmpPlayer){
                [tmpPlayer play];
            }
        }else{
            [BT_debugger showIt:self message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"playSoundInBundle:ERROR. This sound effect is not included in the list of available sounds: %@", theFileName]];
        }
    }

}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
    NSLog(@"Message ID: %@", userInfo);
    NSLog(@"%@", userInfo);

    (void)[Rover didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
}

@end
```

I have been going off the instruction created by the Rover developers at: https://github.com/RoverPlatform/rover-ios

I'm probably missing something simple but guidance would definitely be appreciated.

My logcat's responses to Rover:

```
Rover [4] - [LocationManager.swift.startMonitoring() - Line 76] => Monitoring started.
Rover [4] - [EventOperation.swift.execute() - Line 106] => Submitting event - applicationOpen(2018-02-28 07:46:02 +0000)
Rover [4] - [BluetoothStatusOperation.swift.execute() - Line 34] => Checking Bluetooth status
Rover [4] - [BluetoothStatusOperation.swift.centralManagerDidUpdateState - Line 48] => Determined Bluetooth status - true
Rover [4] - [LocationManager.swift.locationManager(_:didUpdateLocations:) - Line 114] => Received location update.
Rover [0] - [NetworkOperation.swift.execute() - Line 108] => Client error
Rover [4] - [EventOperation.swift.execute() - Line 106] => Submitting event
Rover [0] - [NetworkOperation.swift.execute() - Line 108] => Client error
2018-02-28 02:46:03.792824-0500 app[1540:560757] [CoreBluetooth] XPC connection invalid
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put a breakpoint on the `[Rover startMonitoring];` what happens?
Does rover require you to pass it your APNS token to work?

Comment: Yes I did have to upload a APNS token to Rover back end for notifications to be sent through. I tested the break but it just resulted in the same thing?